# Visual Studio Preview - how to install extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have vs.net preview edition installed, and I am trying to install an extension.  Each time I install it installs for vs.net enterprise 2017 AND not the preview version.

How can I install or copy respective files for the preview edition?